# Do I need to dispose of SWIG-generated objects?

Tags: c#, swig, idisposable

I'm currently using a library built from SWIG into .NET. The documentation for this library doesn't seem to give any information on whether or what of the classes created needs to be disposed. I've also seen discussion on other forums about needing to add code to dispose of child elements that I don't see in the source for this library. On top of all of this, the sample projects and tests for the library do not include `using`s, nor dispose of the objects they create.

So, for the 'average' SWIG object, do I need to dispose of it? It seems that they all have default destructors which delete the object in the underlying C++. If that's the case, then can I just treat them as any other object and let the garbage collector handle them (barring things that would prevent the garbage collector from handling them properly, like circular references and other classic memory leaks). It'd suck to have to wrap all calls/objects to this library with some kind of disposal context or something.

Comment: circular references doesn't prevent objects from being disposed of.

Comment: Did SWIG add finalizers to the c# object? if not, you probably will have a memory leak as the GC won't guarantee that Dispose will be called in all cases.

Comment: It depends on how SWIG was used for creating the wrapper. There is plenty of possibilities for wrapping objects, which you need to manually dispose. At the same time as @JoelLucsy explains, the wrapper can be made such that the generated code includes finalizers, which ensures correct gc.

Comment: @Servy circular references prevent objects from being finalized, and SWIG adds finalizers which dispose.

Comment: @JoelLucsy SWIG does add finalizers and they dispose of the object, though from what I understand not necessarily child objects unless configured right, though that's going to be an issue anyway

Comment: @JensMunk The wrapper does generate finalizers from what I've seen. I guess the question is, is relying on these sufficient? Can I trust that these will be GC'd properly (at some time not in my control) and that guarantees the disposer will be called? I know finalizers are weird and sometimes won't run under certain conditions, but wanted to see if there was any issue in relying on this or if I should be manually disposing anything I have access to.

Comment: I have written some unfortunate typemaps myself, which allocated arrays I forgot to free. I would create a small test of the interface and check for leaks. It depends on how SWIG is used.

Comment: @JensMunk I guess that means it's a super strong "it depends". In the case that the SWIG itself doesn't dispose properly, then there's no way for me to fully dispose of the object though, right? So that's just a bug in the SWIG that needs to be fixed? As in, does that prevent me from using the destructor? I think in that case the garbage collector should still find all of the objects I have created, so it wouldn't help to, for instance, store off all disposable managed references and dispose them manually in a big finally block, as the garbage collector should still dispose of them itself.

Comment: @NateDiamond. No, it is not a bug in SWIG. That would be same as concluding that a compiler is buggy, if a programmer made a program with errors. Using, SWIG it is possible to create very advanced typemaps and like with any other language, it is possible for the programmer to screw things up

Comment: @JensMunk In this case I qualified it just a bit by saying "the SWIG", as in "the SWIG-generated library" or "the SWIG definition" and not in SWIG itself, though I can see how this was misconstrued. I agree with your assertion though.

Comment: @NateDiamond - Circular references do not *prevent* objects from being finalized (and deallocated), they *delay* them from being finalized. No matter what, once an object is unreachable from all GC roots, it will eventually be finalized and GC'd. The only exception is when you deadlock the finalizer thread by doing something silly in your finalizer (like try to grab a lock).

Comment: @antiduh Ah, I didn't know that. So if you have two objects with a circular reference, but both of them have been released from any 'GC roots', they can still be collected? That's great! I had stressed that we used `WeakReference` in those cases because I thought they may prevent collection. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the answers in the comments, it seems that it is overall not necessary in my case. SWIG generated proper finalizers which called the dispose function. It is possible that the dispose function is improperly defined in the SWIG definition, but if this is the case then manually disposing won't help anyway.

Edit: While the initial assertion that disposing of the objects is not necessary, there is a case where it may be useful.

Consider the case where you have a list object exposed through SWIG: `List`
Additionally, you have an 'item' object owned by the list: `Item`

If you were to do this:

```
List list = new List(1, 2, 3);
Item item = list.Get(1);
// list is now available for garbage collection, as there are no longer any P/invokes nor 
// references to it
item.GetValue(); // Can possibly throw AccessViolationException if list
                 // has been garbage collected based on how it cleans up its items.
```

To prevent this from happening, you must prevent `list` from being finalized/disposed until *after* all of them `item`s are done being used. This can be done in a few ways:

- Utilize `GC.KeepAlive()` at the end of all of the uses of `item`s. E.g.

  `item.GetValue();`

  `GC.KeepAlive(list);`
- Utilize the `IDisposable` pattern to ensure deterministic disposal of the parent object. E.g.

```
using(List list = new List(1, 2, 3))
{
    Item item = list.Get(1);
    item.GetValue();
}
```

So manual disposal or using the `IDisposable` pattern is not *necessary* per se, but it can be useful to make sure that your use of the unmanaged objects is safe, consistent, and clear.

Comment: In the using example, what prevents the parent object from being destroyed before item.GetValue()?  Isn't it still possible for the GC to collect it beforehand?

Comment: In general, the GC will keep the object alive until it's no longer being used. The using statement gets compiled into a try/finally block with a `Dispose` call at the end, thereby guaranteeing that there is a call on the object beyond the end of your code block. As stated, the other option is to use `GC.KeepAlive` which has a similar effect, but some people may prefer the disambiguity of the `using` block.

Comment: @StayOnTarget also just curious about the edit that you made. I had wanted to avoid "List" originally in part because it's supposed to denote an unmanaged collection object (and not be confused with the built-in List type). Maybe changing the name to `UnmanagedList` if that's truly preferable? Otherwise IMO going back to `Collection` is less confusing.

Comment: I probably should have left a comment when I made the edit. When I read it I got a little confused between using "collection" as the data structure vs garbage collection. Since the specific nature of the data structure didn't seem too important I thought calling it a list would help avoid that ambiguity. I didn't mean it to look like the .NET List, specifically. Oh also I think there was a minor typo or variation in the variable name ("c" vs. "collection") but that was secondary.